# How to align image and text one under another in two linear layouts for dynamic content

Tags: android

```
xml file --->>>>    
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/dashboard_hs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:fillViewport="false"
        android:scrollbarSize="3dp">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/rlforImgGallery">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/imageGallery"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingTop="50dp">
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/view_name"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageGallery"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Java file---->>>

```
  LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;

            //RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                  //  ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
         //   rp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.imageGallery);
            lp.setMargins(0, 0, 60, 0);
            lp1.setMargins(60,0,150,0);
            lp1.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;

         //   tv.setLayoutParams(rp);
            tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
            imageGallery.addView(imgView);
            //imageGallery.addView(tv);

            name_view.addView(tv);


            //relativeLayout.addView(tv);


            imgView.setLayoutParams(lp);
            tv.setLayoutParams(lp1);
```

I have two lineat layouts inside HorizontalScrollView, one LinearLayout displays the image dynamically and another LinearLayout  display text(i.e name of user) . the problem is,it is not displaying text under the corresponding image.

Answer (score 0):

Since, you are using `WRAP_CONTENT` for both your `ImageView` and `TextView`, they won't align up corresponding. Another troubling point in your layout is the use `<RelativeLayout>` (performance issue here) which can be avoided. I'd suggest you make your parent layout like below:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/dashboard_hs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:fillViewport="false"
    android:scrollbarSize="3dp">  

    <!-- Will add views here -->     

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Now, you can define a fixed 'cell' layout which will hold each of your user data. Define it something like this (vague example):

```
// cell_layout.xml
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/imgView"
        android:src="@android:color/holo_red_dark"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:text="Funk you :)"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Since, we defined the layout ourselves, we are guaranteed a definite arrangement. We can now inflate this layout at runtime:

```
ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.dashboard_hs);

LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

// -----
// Following segment to be repeated for each of your users
LinearLayout ll_main = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.cell_layout, scrollView, false);

ImageView imgView = (ImageView) ll_main.findViewByIf(R.id.imgView);
imgView.setImageResource(R.id.user);
TextView textView = (TextView) ll_main.findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setText("UserName");

scrollView.addView(ll_main);

// -----
```

Done! Let me know if you have any confusion.